# XML Deserialization C# gives error for valid document

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-deserialization

I have a lot of XML files with the same structure. Many of them working OK, but for some XmlSerializer gives me an error but when I put the document in xml validator - it says that document is correct.

Deserialization code:

```
var document = serializer.Deserialize(File.OpenRead(file));
```

Error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (504, 8). ---> System.Xml.XmlException: Unexpected node type Element. ReadElementString method can only be called on elements with simple or empty content. Line 504, position 8.
  at System.Xml.XmlReader.ReadElementString()
  at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderPatentdocument.Read33_Claimtext(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
  at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderPatentdocument.Read34_Claim(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
  at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderPatentdocument.Read35_Claims(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
  at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderPatentdocument.Read43_Patentdocument(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
  at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderPatentdocument.Read44_patentdocument()
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(Stream stream)
```

The part of the document where it gives the error:

```
<text>12. Führungsschiene nach einem der Ansprüche 2 bis 11, dadurch gekennzeichnet, daß in den beiden Nutwänden (<b>11<i>a</i>, 11</b><i>a′)</i> einander gegenüberliegende Bohrungen (<b>14</b><i>a</i>, <b>14</b><i>a</i>′) vorgesehen sind, von denen die eine Bohrung (<b>14</b><i>a</i>′) durch das Einsatzteil (<b>15</b><i>a)</i> ver­schlossen ist.</text>
```

I suppose it is because of inline html tags inside because it complains about this line on position of **i** tag

```
<b>11<i>a</i>, 11</b>
```

But for example this xml is correct according to XmlSerializer and it is possible to deserialize it:

```
<text>9. Führungsschiene nach Anspruch 8, dadurch gekennzeichnet, daß der Ansatz (<b>20</b>) die Zuführfläche (<b>25</b>) aufweist.</text>
```

So my question why xml validator says that the document is valid and XmlSerializer cannot deserialize it? Is it possible to have a workaround without changing the document?

Comment: You need a set of classes in your application that matches the xml file.  The serialize/de-serialize isn't automatic.

Comment: The XmlSerializer is terrible.  Oh, you know that now.  Never mind.  Try using linq to xml.

Comment: The document isn't valid XML. It contains *unknown XML tags* called `b` and `i`. You have to *encode* HTML string if you want to include it in a XML document

Comment: @Will no XML tool will accept raw HTML inside a text element

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos but there are tools that are easier to use when your xml is funky.

Comment: @Will all of them will complain about raw HTML. In this case, XmlSerializer works correctly.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos IIRC linq to xml wouldn't complain unless attempting to navigate to child nodes of <text>

Comment: @Will only if LINQ to XML *didn't* use a schema for validation (bad idea). The bad element would still throw when the OP tried to use the element. Worst case, the exception would occur in production inside an MVC view

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos well, considering this is funky xml, validating would be a bad idea.  IRL, you sometimes have to use funky xml, and that means you need a tool that's a little loose with the specs, as long as you don't try anything weird like navigating child elements where you know absolutely you only want the text value of the content of the node.    Not wanting to annoy the OP more with this bickering, I bid a good day to you, sir.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos while HTML is often not valid XML, the fragment shown here is [perfectly valid XML](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_complex_mixed.asp). It's not a valid `string`, which is why the serializer doesn't like it - but it could be deserialized to some other structure.

Comment: @CharlesMager check the error message - the deserializer complains about a simple element. The call stack shows that the deserializer was generated from an XSD which expects text in the `<text>` element. Either the XSD is wrong, or there is a bug in the serializer. If the data comes from a third party, the OP may have to find a way to work with the invalid data

Comment: @syned where does the file come from? Is it test data or actual data that comes from a third party? Can you fix the serializer to generate a CDATA element ?

Comment: Xml validator http://www.xmlvalidation.com/ is saying that XML is correct

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I do not have an option to add CDATA for the file. Of course I can preprocess file to add CDATA on the fly and then deserialize it.

Comment: @syned that validator doesn't mention XSDs, only the older DTDs. Did you just copy the file or did you include links to valid DTDs? If you just copied the file, the result is meaningless. The problem is that the XSD you used to generate the deserializer expects *simple text content* for `<text>`. Did you generate the XSD based on some sample perhaps?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos even XmlSerializer can deserialize xml with html tags inside without problem, but it has problem when **i** tag inside **b** tag. Updated question.

Comment: I tried to remove these problematic **i** tags from **b** and the rest of html is working perfectly.

Comment: Don't confuse **valid** and **well-formed** xml! Your xml is well-formed, so that the XmlSerializer may it deserialize in general.  But your XML is not valid in accordance with the definition of the classes. Obviously, you should add to your class properties of `b` and `i`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov but it is working correctly with only **b** tags but not with **i** inside **b** tag...

Answer (score 1):

You're right when you point at the inner HTML tags.
Your XML is not valid because you have tags inside a simple (text) element. XmlSerializer doesn't understand and throws an error.

If you have generated the XML files, you **have** to escape the data inside the simple elements **beforehand** :

- with HTML Encode
- Or by encapsulating it in a CDATA tag (`<![CDATA[...]]>`)

Comment: The XML is *not* valid. It contains *XML tags* inside the `<text>` element. HTML tags do not receive any special treatment when they appear inside an XML element, especially a simple element.

Comment: I do not have access to process of generating these files. These are my input files.

Comment: @DarKalimHero I do not have an option to add CDATA for the file. Of course I can preprocess file to add CDATA on the fly and then deserialize it. But I would like to avoid it if it is possible

Comment: It is possible to include html in XML without encoding or CDATA

Comment: OK. What do you want to do, in the end ? What are you going to do with the XML ? Why do you deserialize it ?
Maybe we can find some workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Try *serializing* the instance that is causing you problems. Then you can compare the output of the serialization with the contents of the file you are attempting to deserialize. The difference between the two XML strings will show you where the problem is.

Here is a quick function to serialize an instance of a class to XML:

```
    public static string Serialize<T>(T entity)
    {
        if (entity == null)
            return String.Empty;

        try
        {
            XmlSerializer XS = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            System.IO.StringWriter SW = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            XS.Serialize(SW, entity);
            return SW.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logging.Log(Severity.Error, "Unable to serialize entity", e);
            return String.Empty;
        }
    }
```

If you haven't tried it yet, I would suggest the software [BeyondCompare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) to easily see the difference between the two files.

Comment: i'm not serializing these documents, I have them as an input

Comment: I understand. I'm not sure if it is possible, but can you hand code an instance using the data from the input?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have the following class:

```
public class Foo
{
    //[XmlIgnore]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

And xml of the following form:

```
<Foo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <text>12. Führungsschiene nach einem der Ansprüche 2 bis 11, dadurch gekennzeichnet, daß in den beiden Nutwänden (<b>11<i>a</i>, 11</b><i>a′)</i> einander gegenüberliegende Bohrungen (<b>14</b><i>a</i>, <b>14</b><i>a</i>′) vorgesehen sind, von denen die eine Bohrung (<b>14</b><i>a</i>′) durch das Einsatzteil (<b>15</b><i>a)</i> ver­schlossen ist.</text>
</Foo>
```

Then we can deserialize the data as follows.

```
var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo));
xs.UnknownElement += Xs_UnknownElement;

Foo foo;
using (var fs = new FileStream("test.txt", FileMode.Open))
{
    foo = (Foo)xs.Deserialize(fs);
}
```

Subscribe `XmlSerializer` to `UnknownElement` event.

In the event handler manually set our property to the data.

```
private static void Xs_UnknownElement(object sender, XmlElementEventArgs e)
{
    var foo = (Foo)e.ObjectBeingDeserialized;
    foo.Text = e.Element.InnerXml;
}
```

Please note that the property name should not match the xml node name (case sensitive). Only in this case the event is triggered. If the names match, use the `XmlIgnore` attribute.